# DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to track down the cause of an Entity Framework `InvalidOperationException` in an ASP.NET Core project. The exception suggests using `DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging`.

In my Startup.cs I have:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList");
        opt.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

The problem is it doesn't seem to do anything. The exception message I get is exactly the same and still suggests using `DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What causes the exception in the first place -- how do you reproduce it? Not much point focusing on what's not solving the problem if it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: The problem in this case is that `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` is having no effect.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood "the exception suggests using ..." as it suggesting that as a way to actually solve whatever was causing the exception, but it's only suggesting that as a way to get more detail about the exception itself. Do you at least have a stack trace? (Whether or not you get that somewhere should be independent of this option; if you have no stack trace, configure logging for your application.)

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem. Solved it by using the `OnConfiguring` method in the `DbContext` itself, rather than the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup`.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
}
```

This option is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#other-dbcontext-configuration).

Answer (score 11):

Got this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type ''
> cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for
> {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities,
> ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
> attached. Consider using
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> conflicting key values.

After enabling `options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();` like this in .NET 5

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    });
```

The exception turned into this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type ''
> cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id:
> 5}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities,
> ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
> attached.

The error turned out to be a `List<MyEntity>()` that contained a reference back to the value I was updating.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to remove "GetConnectionString". It was like this,



public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DefaultConnection"]);
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    });

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that's the way to enable it. This should work

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
    {
        opt.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried this option, but didn't work for me. It still showed the original error message without additional info. I could only get it to work with @christian suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is with the existing data.

Please check the related tables in the database and confirm that the data is already satisfying the foreign key constraint you want to add.

The database will not be able to add the constraint if the existing data does not already satisfy it.

If you find it laborious to update the data and it is just for testing, you can clear all the records in the two tables.